# how to require jQuery in Preload.js

Tags: jquery, electron

All

I am more fimiliar with jQuery than the native Javascript to manipulate DOM.
The problem is that jQuery does not work in Preload.js even though I require it using const $=require('jquery') in Preload.js.The error message shown in the brower console is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'createElement')"

I want to use desktopCaturer module to capture the screen and I followed the document to add the codes as following.

```
 // Main Process.
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] 
}).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source.name === 'Electron') {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('SET_SOURCE', source.id)
      return
    }
  }
})

    // preload.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.on('SET_SOURCE', async (event, sourceId) => {
  try {
    const stream = await
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: false,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
          minWidth: 1280,
          maxWidth: 1280,
          minHeight: 720,
          maxHeight: 720
        }
      }
    })
    handleStream(stream)
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e)
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
 
***In this functin, I want to use jQuery to control html DOM dynamically***
}

function handleError (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is designed to be used on the HTML DOM tree. It has no use in the main process of your Electron application. Therefore, there is no need to even worry about integrating it into your `preload.js` script.

Instead, just include it like you would for a typical website, in-between your `<head>` tags or after your closing `</body>` tag, using relative file reference.

```html
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi, midnight-coding! I reedited my question. please refer to the my question. I want to use jQuery in the function of handleStream to manipulate html DOM. Is it possible?

Comment: It may be... I would need to look into it a bit further. What do you want to do to the DOM (dynamically) in this function? jQuery is a large library to load if its use is only minor. Have you seen [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)? Modern browsers, Chromium in this case, makes the need for jQuery just about obsolete.

Comment: Hi, midnight-coding! thank you for your help! what I wanted to do was that I want to get to all of media strems from main process and render with <video> element in renderer process. Anyway, I have resolved this problem using ipc module. There are still a lot of thing for me to study , but it's interesting to solve the problems one by one!

Comment: DOM interaction in preload.js has it's uses. Such as registering ipc commands to close application to an "Exit" button for example. But yes, jquery would be a but overkill in such a case.